# Selecting a same column from two different tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I have made two tables in a database : Table:Users and Table:Cars...
When a user enters information, i want it to be stored in all columns of both tables.

```
Table: Users
User_id    name    email_id    password   carplate_no


Table: Cars
carplate_no     email_id    mobile_no
```

How should i do that? Should i use foreign keys or joins?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  What information?  What does the data look like?  What do you want it to look like?  As for foreign keys and joins, the answer is "yes".

Comment: your data model didn't effeciently.why you storing email_id in both tables any reason?

Comment: Will not argue why you put same information on two tables. But you can do it by creating a trigger. When you insert data on Users table, the trigger will update (or insert) data in Cars table. Google "triggers".